# Why is the cursor only changing to a hand around the edges of a textbox and why is a horizontal scrollbar appearing?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There are a few aesthetic problems with my GUI that I can't quite figure out. The first one is my mouse over. I have a `TextBlock` with a `MouseUp` Event attached to it and I want the cursor to change to a hand when I mouse over so in the xaml I used `Cursor="Hand"` as shown below

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="AttachFileTextBlock" Foreground="Blue" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="16" MouseUp="AttachFileTextBlock_MouseUp" 
           Cursor="Hand">
    <Underline>Attach Screen Shots</Underline>
</TextBlock>
```

However the hand only appears around the edges and furthermore the actual text is not clickable, only clicking the edges trigger the mouse up event.

My other problem is in my `UserControl`, a `HorizontalScrollBar` is appearing even though I clearly set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` in my `ScrollViewer`

Here is the complete xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Client.App.Support.ListOfScreenShots"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="520" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox Name="_listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ''}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="550"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Name="_image" Grid.Column="0" Height="400" Width="550" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment ="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding ''}"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Button Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="_addscreenshot" Content="Select Screenshot" 
                                    Height="30" Width="150" Margin="3.5,0,3.5,7"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="_removescreenshot" Content="Remove Screenshot" 
                                    Height="30" Width="150" Margin="3.5,0,3.5,7"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I am just starting to learn WPF in depth and I really really hate it right now. If this is supposed to be an improvement on other methods of creating UIs I can't even imagine what its predecessors were like. Hopefully it will all click some day.

Comment: Your XAML is wrong. Don't hate WPF. Instead, learn how to use it properly.

Comment: @HighCore your comment is not very useful. Where is my xaml wrong?

Comment: For one, I strongly suggest you get [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It's a free, open source tool that helps **greatly** in debugging WPF layout-specific or general UI issues. It allows you to visualize the Visual tree of a running application and see (and modify) any properties from any UI element.

Comment: Have you customized the `ListBox.Template` anywhere in your application?

Comment: I didn't customize it anywhere.

Comment: then remove the `ScrollViewer`. The default `ListBox` template already has it's own.

Comment: I also tested your `<TextBlock>` and it works fine. It accepts clicking on the text and it does not exhibit undesired behavior. You must have another UI element "blocking" it, placed "above" it (in Z index)

Comment: You were right, I went and cleaned up the xaml for this window and now it works. I still cannot figure out why the horizontal scroll bar is appearing in the usercontrol. I removed scroll viewer, but now the window won't load at all.

Comment: what exactly is happening now? What do you mean by `the window won't load at all`?

Comment: This appears to be a different issue. I will have to post another question.